# cannot return view except welcome from controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

i am new please help thanks.

in controller, i want to return a view, which is not working. the default one 'welcome' is returning but when i create a custom view, it is not returning.

**Route:**

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

**PostController:**

```
public function create()
{
 //return view('create'); //this is not working
   return view('welcome'); //this is working
}
```

**i am searching:**

```
my_project/posts/create
```

Comment: in your console, run `php artisan route:list`. it should show all possible routes and the controllers handling them

Comment: in PostsController: if i write: public function create()
    {
        return view('welcome'); //the default one in laravel,
    }     it works fine.         BUT once i write, public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }                                                                                                                              it does't work and give this error:                                                               
    This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Is there a `create.blade.php` file?

Comment: yes, it is present in view folder. both welcome.blade.php and create.blade.php are in same folder. the welcome.blade.php is working but the other create.blade.php is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a typo there: `PostsController` in on your route argument(plural)

and your controller is `PostController` in singular

match them and it should work as expected

Comment: No sir both are same. means PostsController.

Comment: in PostsController: if i write: public function create()
    {
        return view('welcome'); //the default one in laravel,
    }     it works fine.         BUT once i write, public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }                                                                                                                              it does't work and give this error:                                                               
    This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: hmm ..so your `class PostsController extends Controller` is writing like that ? and that's still not working..?

Comment: both the welcome.blade.php and create.blade.php are in the same folder. the welcome.blade.php is working but the other one create.blade.php is not working.

Comment: Normally you should have an index method as well, please run in the command line `php artisan route:list` like @Chinonso Chukwuogor mentioned and share with us your output

Comment: i created the controller: which contains the CRUD methods. other methods have no code except the create one and in the create i want to return the view. create.blade.php            public function create()
    {
        //return view('posts.create');
        return view('good');
    }

Comment: Domain | Method     | URI         | Name    | Action     | Middleware                          
              GET|HEAD| posts  | posts.index| App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@index  | web                                           POST      | posts             | posts.store   | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store   | web                          GET|HEAD  | posts/create      | posts.create  | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@create  | web          | |        |

Comment: GET|HEAD  | posts/{post}      | posts.show    | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | posts/{post}      | posts.update  | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | posts/{post}      | posts.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | posts/{post}/edit | posts.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@edit    | web

Comment: seems like something is wrong with the file then, what does it contains ? the file create.blade.php can you share this with us?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

Comment: create.blade.php                                                                @extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')

 <form method="post" action="/posts">
  
 <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter title">
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>

Comment: try `@endsection` after the `</form>` tag, let me know if that worked for you

Comment: my bad, I've modified the syntax its @endsection

Comment: Lets make a test, create another file called `test.blade.php`, copy all of the content you have in `create.blade.php` into `test.blade.php` and in your controller simply `return view('test');` do you still get ERROR 500 ?

Comment: sir it was due to the deniel of permission of xampp file, which denied to access to laravel boostrap and session file. i solved with the help of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYaELE7vkWE

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create view blade file in resource/views folder **create.blade.php**

Write below the line in controller file in **index function.**

```
public function index(){
    return view('create');
}
```

Then try to run http://localhost/my_project/posts

OR

Run commad in terminal **php artisan serve**

Then Try to run http://localhost:8000/posts

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue only the welcome page was loading not any other from views directory with artisan server but I put my project folder in Xampp server htdocs folder now it's working fine.